# Best way to get rid of ceramic tiles over an asbestos tiled floor

Tags: tile, removal, asbestos

Just moved house and would like to re-do the kitchen. It looks like the previous owner has cemented ceramic tiles straight over an asbestos tiled floor! I'd like to get rid of the ceramic tile without disturbing the asbestos tiles underneath. Is this possible??

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to get rid of the ceramic tile without disturbing the asbestos tiles underneath. Is this possible??

### Probably not.

The ceramic tiles are serving as the "encapsulant" for the old asbestos, so if you disturb them you'll almost certainly disturb the asbestos.

You can either add another layer on top, or get the whole mess removed by somone licensed to deal with asbestos.